# Not Only But Also

Tags: meaning

Regarding the (Not only A but also B) structure, I know that we can omit “also”. I would like to know can we omit the word “only”.? I would like to know whether the following sentence is (Not Only … But Also) sentence.

> If we turn our gaze to the arguments about justice — **not among** philosophers **but among** ordinary people— we find a more complicated picture.

Which meaning is correct?
(1) Not only among philosophers, but also among ordinary people
(2) Among ordinary people, but not among philosophers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(2) is the meaning of the highlighted sentence.

*Not among philosophers* has the opposite meaning to *not* **only** *among philosophers but...*

Comment: As @Kate said, ‘not among philosophers’ is negative. With 'not only' used here, it may at best be Not among non-philosophers only” (which may not be the intended meaning) but among ordinary people also… Perhaps the intended sense is,  "Among not only the philosophers, but also ordinary people..."